# Change readonly status of field if radio button selected, no jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form, I want to initially have some normal fields and some readonly fields. Then a radio button with two options, if it's the default option nothing changes, if they select the second then the readonly fields become editable.

I need to do this without jquery.

Here's the form

```
<form name="newstock" action="newstock-save.php" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="individual" value="1" checked> Fruit<br>
<input type="radio" name="individual" value="0"> Veges<br><br>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Item name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Packing</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="packing_name" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unit</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="packing_unit" readonly></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please assist

Comment: _“Please assist”_ - please show your attempt! The purpose of this site is not to write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the IDs in your HTML.

```
<form name="newstock" action="newstock-save.php" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="individual" value="1" id="individual1" checked> Fruit<br>
<input type="radio" name="individual" value="0" id="individual0"> Veges<br><br>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Item name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Packing</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="packing_name" id="packing_name" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unit</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="packing_unit" id="package_unit" readonly></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then, get the elements with **getElementById**, and add **EventListeners** in your JS.

```
const individual1  = document.getElementById("individual1"),
      individual0  = document.getElementById("individual0"),
      packing_name = document.getElementById("packing_name"),
      package_unit = document.getElementById("package_unit");

individual1.addEventListener("change", function(){
  packing_name.value = '';
  package_unit.value = '';
  packing_name.readOnly = true;
  package_unit.readOnly = true;
});

individual0.addEventListener("change", function(){
  packing_name.readOnly = false;
  package_unit.readOnly = false;
});
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVyVGx

Answer (score 1):

You can remove readonly for an element with the following two options,

**Option 1:**

```
document.getElementById('elementId').removeAttribute('readonly');
```

**Option 2:**

```
document.getElementById('elementId').readOnly = false;
```

Use any of the above code on change of the radio button.

For triggering the click event use the attribute **onclick**, add the below as an attribute to the input element.

```
onclick="callBack()"
```

And inside your JS,

```
function callBack() {
  document.querySelector('input[name="individual"]:checked').value; // get the value and check it with an if condition.
}
```

Comment: how would I make that trigger when they click the radio button?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.querySelector to get selected radio value based on the value you can disable or enable any I/p field dynamically in JavaScript

**For Getting Radio value**

```
document.getElementById(“input[id=‘eleid’]:checked”).value
```

**for enabling / disabling**

```
document.getElementById(elem).disabled = true/false
```